# .htaccess страницы со слешем и без на конце - разные страницы

Tags: html, .htaccess, маршрутизация

Задача простая, но мне непосильная:
Сайт на чистом html, пытаюсь настроить .htaccess так, чтобы адреса со слешем на конце интерпретировались как вход в папку с открытием index.html, а без слеша, как страница. А так же, чтоб у главной страницы всегда стоял на конце слеш (по возможности ^^ ). Окончание .html и index.html ессесно не надо.

```
https://site.ru/ = https://site.ru/index.html
https://site.ru/page = https://site.ru/page.html
https://site.ru/page/ = https://site.ru/page/index.html
```

Вот что я сваял, но это лишь помогло убрать .html окончание и убрать .index.html у домена..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html
</IfModule>
```

Суть логики проста, но я уже себе сломал голову, пытаясь это реализовать, а учитывая, что я не сплю уже 20 часов, так совсем тяжко.. Помогите люди добрые...

Answer (score 1):

Перелопатив кучу сайтов и убив на это примерно сутки, я все таки нашел вариант решения, который охватывает все задачи.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ([^\s]*)\.html(\?[^\s]*)?
RewriteRule (.*) %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.html [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```